# Product not show after remove “size chart”extension

Tags: magento-1.9

i  having problem. please help!

I recently installed "size chart" extension and removed, and after that,

in my all product not show in pages and not able to add new product in admin panel. But all website to work fine.

Comment: Yes, Its database problem so I upload old database and its work fine